# how to link js tabs with the tab content using a var in the div and href?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tabs

I know it is a silly question, but it annoys me a lot.

I have a page with tabs. I want to generate the tabs dynamicaly using an array and a loop. The question is I could not link the tab and the tab content together.

Here is my example code:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<i a href = '$Tabtitle'>$Tabtitle</a></i>
</ul>

<div id = "$Tabtitle">
<!--tab content-->
</div>
```

The result is all tab content are under one tab (they should be separated under different tabs), and changing tabs won't change the tab content.

I tried to do these:
Change href = '#$Tabtitle', not working.
change

```
<div id ="<?php echo $Tabtitle;?>"
```

still not working.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should probably be clearer about what's happening that you don't expect and give some insight as to what all these variables contain. Code in a question should be *minimal* and *reproducible*. Make it as easy as possible for someone to help you solve the problem. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you! It is my fault. Don't know how to edit my question. The problem is all tabs just contain the same information----they list out all tab contents in one page!

Comment: There is an [edit] link on your question right under the tags at the bottom. You can either press that or the link I just put in this comment.

Comment: Let me try to clarify it. I want to use vars as tab ids, and use loop to generate them. But they don't link together.

Comment: For people to be able to solve this problem, you would need to include (1) the error you get (2) any debugging you did (3) any research you did (4) the current output (5) the expected output and (6) a self-contained example that can be tested by others.

Comment: self-contained example part is hard, since I used many .css could not listed here. But I will try my best. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. You can also read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the poor question, but since I resolved the problem, I'd rather put it here in case others may find it useful.

The code should be like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<i a href = 'path/$var#$Tabtitle'>$Tabtitle</a></i>
</ul>

<div id = "$Tabtitle">
<!--tab content-->
</div>
```

And it works!
Thank you!